# How to run nodejs and reactjs in Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have a nodejs app to run backend and another reactjs app to run frontend for a website, then put to docker image. But I don't know how to deal with `CMD` command in `Dockerfile`. Does Docker have any command solve this?

I thought that i could use `docker-compose` to build 2 separate image but it seem to be wasted because `node` image has to be installed 2 times.

Does anyone has solution?

Comment: If you have two images that are both `FROM node` then Docker will share the underlying image, if the space for your Node installation is the biggest concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb, single process per container.

> I thought that I could use docker-compose to build 2 separate image 
>   but it seems to be wasted because node image has to be installed 2 
>   times.

First thing, manage 2 separate docker image is fine but running two process in the container [is not fine at all](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container).

second thing, You do not need to build 2 separate images, if you can run two processes from the same code then you can run both applications from single docker-compose.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  react-app:
    image: myapp:latest
    command: node server.js
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  node-app:
    image: myapp:latest  
    ports:
      - 3001:3001  
    command: react-scripts start"
```

> Each container should have only one concern. Decoupling applications
>   into multiple containers makes it easier to scale horizontally and
>   reuse containers. For instance, a web application stack might consist
>   of three separate containers, each with its own unique image, to
>   manage the web application, database, and an in-memory cache in a
>   decoupled manner.
>
> **Limiting each container to one process is a good rule of thumb**

[Dockerfile Best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Comment: sorry for replying slowly. I just have tried with your ```docker-compose``` file, and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whether put your backend and front-end inside the same container is a design choice (Remember that docker container are designed to share a lot of resources from the host machine). 
You can use a shell script and run that shell script with `CMD` in your Dockerfile.